# all elements that belong to at least one of the sets Ak

Tags: analysis

<Introduction to Real Analysis.P.3)
For a finite collection of sets {A1, A2, . • • , An}, their union is the set A consisting of all elements that belong to at least one of the sets Ak, and their intersection consists of all elements that belong to all of the sets Ak.
So my question is: what does it mean all elements that belong to at least one of the sets Ak? For example, all elements that belong to two of the sets? three of the sets? Wouldn't this be the intersection of the these sets?

Comment: Simple example with two sets $A_1$ and $A_2$ where $A_1 = \{ 1,2,3 \}$ and $A_2 = \{ 2,9,10 \}$. We have that e.g. element $1$ belongs to *at least* one set $A_k$ (it belongs to $A_1$ and not to $A_2$) while element $2$ belongs to *all* sets $A_k$ (it belongs to both $A_1$ and $A_2$).

Comment: “at least one” means “one or more”

Comment: It may be instructive to try to define the “union of sets” yourself. Then compare it with the definition from the book.

Comment: Appreciate......